# three phase diagram plot in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to generate a three phase saturation plot in Matlab.

I found this code in matlab and it does generate something similar but not exactly the same

As much it looks simple, I dont know how to adjust the values to match the plot in the figure. As I dont have a specific values. 
Even if there is a way to generate the shading of the colors that changes from one edge to another that would be fine
Any suggestions please

```
% Main file for ternary plot
close all; clear all; clc;
A = [...

    1.000   0.000   0.000
    0.000   1.000   0.000
    0.000   0.000   1.000
    0.330   0.330   0.340
    0.340   0.000   0.660
    0.000   0.340   0.660
    0.000   0.160   0.840
    0.160   0.000   0.840
    0.000   0.153   0.847
   ];
l=length(A);
% A(l+1,:)=[1 0 0 6];
% A(l+2,:)=[0 1 0 30];
% A(l+3,:)=[0 0 1 1];
% ... and the GPR velocity
% v=0.29./sqrt(A(:,4));
data = [...

    0.0
    0.0
    0.0
    0.419
    0.273
    0.090
    0.014
    0.010
    0.00
    ];
v = data;
figure;
% Plot the data
% First set the colormap (can't be done afterwards)
colormap(jet)
[hg,htick,hcb]=tersurf(A(:,1),A(:,2),A(:,3),v);
% Add the labels
hlabels=terlabel('Gas','Water','Oil');

set(hg(:,3),'color','m')
set(hg(:,2),'color','c')
set(hg(:,1),'color','y')
%--  Modify the labels
set(hlabels,'fontsize',12)
set(hlabels(3),'color','m')
set(hlabels(2),'color','c')
set(hlabels(1),'color','y')
%--  Modify the tick labels
set(htick(:,1),'color','y','linewidth',3)
set(htick(:,2),'color','c','linewidth',3)
set(htick(:,3),'color','m','linewidth',3)
%--  Change the colorbar
set(hcb,'xcolor','w','ycolor','w')
%--  Modify the figure color
set(gcf,'color',[0 0 0.3])
%-- Change some defaults
set(gcf,'paperpositionmode','auto','inverthardcopy','off')
```

[image]